# Why getting file not found error for mvn -version even after adding environment variables?

Tags: java, maven, java-8, maven-3

I downloaded apache maven 3.6.3 and added the "C:\apache-maven-3.6.3" and "C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin" as environment variables "MAVEN_HOME" and Path respectively. But still I am getting the below error on running "mvn -version" command in command prompt. I added JAVA_HOME and java Path as "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212" and "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\bin" also. Please let me know the solution.

```
D:\Users\user1>mvn -version
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Users\user1/m2/logging
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:270)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Configurator.configure(Configurator.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.configure(Launcher.java:127)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:400)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
```

Comment: *`D:\Users\user1/m2/logging`* is inconsistent. You want `D:/Users/user1/m2/logging`

Comment: try with `mvn -X` and attach the result

Comment: @JRichardsz getting same error only for mvn -X command also

Comment: @g00se There is nothing called logging directory/ file in m2 folder of my D drive. It seems irrelevant for the command I give. Kindly explain.

Comment: *Something* is looking for that file: *`java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Users\user1/m2/logging`*

Comment: Remove all environment variables and only keep the setting to `PATH=C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;...` and of course JAVA_HOME nothing else is needed. Afterwards restart the console and try `mvn --version` on plain command line...

Comment: this never happens on linux :b. Did you see the java_home, maven_home and other variables in the result of `mvn -X` ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Tried your solution but still facing the same issue

Comment: Have you closed the existing command line afterwards changed the environment and then reopened the commend line...if don't do that the changes to the environment will not being updated. The same issue means the same output as posted? Do you have an old Maven version installed?